# Flex: Fill with panel the rest of the surface

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to fill the rest of the surface until my footer with a panel and the style `panel-grow-shrink` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

```css
.flex-column-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-content: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.panel-grow-shrink {
    order: 0;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    align-self: stretch;
 background-color:red;
}

.btn-toolbar {
    /*margin-left: -5px;*/
}
.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
}
body{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column-container">
    <div>
        <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-grow-shrink">
    Panel to fill the rest of the region
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" >Button1</button>
            <button type="button" >Button2</button>
            <button type="button" >Button3</button>
            <button type="button" >Button4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add the footer at the bottom of the page and the panel `panel-grow-shrink` should take the height of the rest of the surface. In this example the footer is not at the bottom.

Comment: It is working, try to inspect the elements

Comment: I want to add my footer at the bottom of the page.

Comment: If i can give you an advice, you shouldn't set height to things, there is no need to think about filling space if you istance everything dinamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the flex-column-container to display flex. This means the div containing the title and the div with class "panel-body" will be displayed in a flex way. "panel-grow-shrink" and "btn-toolbar" are inside "panel-body" and will not be displayed in a flex way, since there is no display:flex css on the "panel-body". I have added a code snippet to clarify.

```css
.flex-column-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  background-color:blue;
  min-height:350px;
}

.title{
}

.panel-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:pink;
    flex-grow:1; /*expands to fill remaining space*/
}

.panel-grow-shrink {
   flex-grow:1;/*expands to fill remaining space*/
 background-color:red;
}

.btn-toolbar {
    /*margin-left: -5px;*/
}
.panel-body {
    /*padding: 15px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-column-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1><span>Title</span></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="panel-grow-shrink">
    Panel to fill the rest of the region
        </div>
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" >Button1</button>
            <button type="button" >Button2</button>
            <button type="button" >Button3</button>
            <button type="button" >Button4</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```